# Django Mac os x authentication integration

Tags: django, apache, osx-server

Mac OS X has users and groups. When using OS X Server the user names and passwords can be used by apache under Basic Authentication. Running under Https it is a convenient way to have web access for users to the server.

I'm setting up a site which is used by users both from the LAN at the office, where the server authenticates and then serves up the user's home page in Mac OS X. I also am using Django to serve up a site over HTTPS.

I've looked at request.META and cannot find the Apache authenticated user name. I was thinking I could let Apache do the authentication for me in this sort of setup. Anyone have any ideas about integrating Django and Apache authentication in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I think for using HTTP authentication you will have to use Django 1.3, as it added the HTTP authentication backend to integrate with the django authentication framework.

The [docuementation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/) might prove more useful here.

Comment: Hmm. This gets me closer. However I don't have REMOTE_USER in the request.META object. I suspect I also have an issue on the Apache configuration side.